# How do I post large data to the server?

Tags: javascript, string, post, xmlhttprequest

I have to send the XML from the client side to the server side.

The method adopted by me was that:

First the xml is converted to string in the javascript and then post as a uri

**var url = '/perl/set_zorder_xml.cgi'+'?'+xmlString+'&'+location+'&'+'nocache='+randomnumber;**

xml string is the string that contains the xml in string form.

The post function looks like this:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            req_anno = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req_anno.open("POST", url, false);
            req_anno.send();
            }
```

The problem is that when my xml string is very large then html 414 error occurs i.e url too large.
Is there any way out, Javascript and perl is used

Comment: Wouldn't you normally send() the XML, and not add it to the querystring, seems like a strange thing to do, as you're making a GET request with a POST request.

Comment: I am new so might be i have made a mess can you ellobrate the procedure that can be followed since now my structure is like this

Comment: if you use `jquery`, you may launch the request as a genuine POST request with the `ajax` methods. this basically sends content together with the url. this content corresponds to the url-parameters and their values and doesn't fall under the url length limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you're doing a POST request, you're still sending the data in the querystring of the URL. Instead you should move the data to be sent as POST data, and remove it from the URL.

```
req_anno.open("POST", '/perl/set_zorder_xml.cgi', false);
req_anno.send('xml=' + encodeURIComponent(xmlString));
```

The XHR [`.send()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest#send%28%29) method accepts the string to be sent as the request body (ie POST data).

Comment: at the server side where is the string value of the xml. I mean which parameter hold the value of the xml in string format

Comment: In the code above the data will be in the POST parameter named `xml`. As you can see in the `.send()` call, I set `xml=`, you can change this to whatever parameter name you want.

Comment: at server side:
my code looks like

use CGI;
use URI::Escape;
require 'globalvariables.pl';

# Get STDIN:
$valStr=read(STDIN, $stdin, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});

$paramVal=CGI::param();

print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";   
# header tells client you send XML
print "\r\n";  
                   
                   
print $valStr; 

**but how to print the value that is of xml.** Sorry for basic stuff

Comment: I got the answer it is in :
use CGI;
use URI::Escape;
require 'globalvariables.pl';

# Get STDIN:
read(STDIN, $stdin, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});

$paramVal=CGI::param();

print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";   
# header tells client you send XML
print "\r\n";  
                  
#the parameters contains the query string                     
$parameters=$ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}; 

print $stdin;

Comment: Glad you got it working, you can also use `use CGI;$q = new CGI;my $value = $q->param('xml');` I think.